# Conexion a 2 base de datos sql server c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

Buen día, quiero conectarme a dos bases de datos en la misma instancia SQL server, normalmente con una cadena de conexión como esta quedaría  `connectionString = "Server=192.168.1.10\\COMPAC; Database=prueba; user=sa; password=*********; integrated security= false";` pero si quiero agregar una segunda base de datos no se como hacerle

Comment: No es necesario revelar contraseñas en la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Para 2 conexiones a una base de datos es necesario crear 2 conexiones:

```csharp
public class SqlData
{
  private SqlConnection connectionServer1 = new SqlConnection("Server=192.168.1.10\COMPAC; Database=prueba1; user=sa; password=compac$1; integrated security= false");
  private SqlConnection connectionServer2 = new SqlConnection("Server=192.168.1.10\COMPAC; Database=prueba2; user=sa; password=compac$1; integrated security= false");

  public SqlData()
  {
    connectionServer1.Open();
    connectionServer2.Open();
  }

  private object FetchData1(string queryString)
  {
    using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connectionServer1))
    {
      // Readout
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En este caso es posible omitir la propiedad **"database"** de la cadena de conexion y utilizar la la ruta completa en los querys BaseDatos+Esquema+Tabla, un codigo vale mas que mil palabras:

```
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server=192.168.1.10\\COMPAC; user=sa; password=*********; integrated security= false");

        conn.Open();
        
        //Consulta a base de datos 1
        string queryString = "Select * from prueba1.dbo.table1";
        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryString, conn))
        {
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt1);
        }

        //Consulta a base de datos 2

        queryString = "Select * from prueba2.dbo.table2";
        DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryString, conn))
        {
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt2);
        }

        //Puedes combinar ambas en un query
        queryString = "Select t1.id, t1.text, t2.name from prueba1.dbo.table1 t1" +
                       " inner join prueba2.dbo.table2 t2" +
                       " on t1.id=t2.id";
        DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryString, conn))
        {
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt3);
        }
        conn.Close();
```